# Google Analytics 4 Purchase event updates

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce, google-analytics-4

We have noticed purchase events in our Google Analytics 4 report coming through in Realtime as '**ecommerce_purchase**', rather than '**purchase**', as it has always been:

[image]

We have not updated anything within the GTM container or the GA4 report. The GTM Purchase tag continues to reference 'purchase' as the event, and is untouched:

[image]

Up until last Friday (*16/01/21*) our report was only ever receiving a 'purchase' event until this weekend where this new 'ecommerce_purchase' is now being tracked. It seems intermittent, where we can see 'ecommerce_purchase' in the GA4 Debugview, then run the same test a minute later where we then see 'purchase' as the event tracked in Debugview.

The dataLayer and code have remained untouched. When testing ourselves and viewing the tags fired in the GTM Preview, the 'purchase' event triggers our GTM tag, and the dataLayer displays all information from this event with no mention of 'ecommmerce_purchase'.

Would anyone have any idea as to what is causing this? Or, is anyone experiencing this as well?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check in your Create Events/Modify Events to see if someone created a new event based on the purchase event or modified the purchase event coming in and renamed it to ecommerce_purchase.

Go to All Events > Create Events or Modify Events to see if any have been created.